# ABSPATH doesn't work

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

ABSPATH only works when it's used by itself. For example:

```
require_once(ABSPATH);
```

will return:

```
/vagrant/
```

which is along the lines of what i want.

But when i go

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

it will return;

```
ABSPATHwp-load.php
```

Which is not what i want.

I'm calling ABSPATH outside of the wordpress 'environment' with in part of a plugin.

Comment: I mean, if it's `outside of the wordpress 'environment'` it's not expected to work. Could you edit your question and add in more context of what you mean when you say it's both outside of WordPress yet inside a plugin?

Comment: Well when i used ABSPATH by itself it works as it should, it gives the root of the site

Comment: @Callum why are you trying to load `wp-load.php`? Bootstrapping WordPress inside a standalone file in a theme or plugin can be fragile and dangerous, a security risk. Have you considered using a hook and exiting early for form handling/uploads/etc, or using a REST API for AJAX instead?

Comment: @TomJNowell Is there any articles that show me how to do the methods you're mentioning?

Comment: @Callum there are thousands, but I trust you can google, I don't have a specific article to recommend to you. You could also ask how to create a shortcode or how to add an oembed provider on this site